# how to pass single quote to applescript by zsh alias

Tags: bash, shell, applescript, alias, zsh

i am use applescript to login ssh by gateway。

```
alias  sshtoxxxx="osascript  ~/workspace/script/applescript/fox/ssh_xxxx.applescript  root@10.10.1.199  hFVDa4d\'vLe"
```

when password contains ' , it will  can not login.

and the applescript is below  also it is no use

```
on run argv
    set arg1 to (item 1 of argv)
    set arg2 to (item 2 of argv)
    testFunc(arg1,arg2)
    sshxxx(arg1,arg2)    
end run

on sshxxx(target,password)
    tell application "iTerm"
        reopen
        activate
        tell the current window
            create tab with default profile   
            tell the current tab
                tell the current session
                    write text "clear"
                    write text "logfin the gate way host"
                    delay 0.2
                    repeat until "xxxxx" is in contents
                    end repeat
                    write text "clear"
                    set targetText to "ssh " & target            
                    write text   targetText            
                    repeat until "password" is in contents
                    end repeat
                    write text password
                end  tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end sshxxx
```

Comment: I don't know how `iTerm` behaves but try `write text quoted form of password`

Answer (score 1):

The question is not related to Applescript. Zsh doesn't care, what programming language the called executable is written in.

If you want to use an alias, your approach is correct. Applescript will see the password parameter as *hFVDa4d'vL*. However, for ease of debugging, I recommend using a Zsh function instead of an alias; here you have to drop the backslash:

```
function sshtoxxxx {
  osascript  ~/workspace/script/applescript/fox/ssh_xxxx.applescript  root@10.10.1.199  "hFVDa4d'vLe"
}
```